# Solving $\sin^6x+\sin^4x\cdot \cos^2x=\sin^2x \cdot \cos^3x+\sin x \cdot \cos^5x$

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

> Solve:
>   $$\sin^6x+\sin^4x\cdot \cos^2x=\sin^2x \cdot \cos^3x+\sin x \cdot \cos^5x$$

Solution -
We have -
$$\sin ^6\left(x\right)+\sin ^4\left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(x\right)=\sin ^3\left(x\right)\cos ^3\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\cos ^5\left(x\right)$$Subtracting $\sin ^3\left(x\right)\cos ^3\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\cos ^5\left(x\right)$ from both the sides -
$$\sin ^6\left(x\right)+\cos ^2\left(x\right)\sin ^4\left(x\right)-\cos ^3\left(x\right)\sin ^3\left(x\right)-\cos ^5\left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)=0$$Factoring the equation as -
$$\sin \left(x\right)\sin ^5\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\sin ^3\left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\sin ^2\left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\cos ^5\left(x\right)$$Taking $sin(x)$ common -
$$\sin \left(x\right)\left(\sin ^5\left(x\right)+\sin ^3\left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(x\right)-\sin ^2\left(x\right)\cos ^3\left(x\right)-\cos ^5\left(x\right)\right)$$
Factoring $\left(\sin ^5\left(x\right)+\sin ^3\left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(x\right)-\sin ^2\left(x\right)\cos ^3\left(x\right)-\cos ^5\left(x\right)\right)$ as -
$$\left(\sin ^5\left(x\right)+\sin ^3\left(x\right)\cos ^2\left(x\right)\right)+\left(-\sin ^2\left(x\right)\cos ^3\left(x\right)-\cos ^5\left(x\right)\right)$$Now, factor out $-cos^3x$, then $sin^3 x$ and finaly $sin^2x + cos^2x$, you'll get the equation as (I have not shown these steps. If you have some difficulty solving these steps on your own, please feel free to ask me for them.) -
$$\sin \left(x\right)\left(\sin ^2\left(x\right)+\cos ^2\left(x\right)\right)\left(\sin \left(x\right)-\cos \left(x\right)\right)\left(\sin ^2\left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(x\right)+\cos ^2\left(x\right)\right)=0$$Using $\cos ^2\left(x\right)+\sin ^2\left(x\right)=1$ $\rightarrow$
$$\sin \left(x\right)\left(-\cos \left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\right)\left(1+\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)\right)=0$$Now solve each of the parts separately. You'll be getting the answers as -
$$\boxed{x=2\pi n,\:x=\pi +2\pi n,\:x=\frac{\pi }{4}+\pi n}$$

The question is very straightforward, sorry about that. But $x=\pi +2\pi n$ can it be considered a solution? Ask me why I think $ \pi + \pi.2n $ is not a solution, because $ \tan = 0, \sin = 0 $, so $ x = 0, x = n. \pi $

Comment: @Moo I tested and it works, always gives zero .... but see my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\sin^6(x)+\sin^4(x)(1-\sin^2(x))-\sin^2(x)\cos^3(x)-\sin(x)\cos^5(x)=0$$ and this is
$$\sin^4(x)-\cos^3(x)(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=0$$
and this is
$$\sin^4(x)-\cos^3(x)=0$$ this can be reduced to
$$\cos^4(x)-\cos^3(x)-2\cos^2(x)+1=0$$